# Is it haram to hide that you are a muslim?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, religion

Assalamualaikum, i am a born muslim, i actually don't talk about religion that much but if someone asks, i don't tell them my religion because many people have just this hate for us Muslims, so will it be haram to hide my religion?

Comment: No, it's not Haram because even the earliest of Sahaba were advised to practice their faith in hiding until Umar (RA) became a Muslim. On the flip side, if your imaan is strong, any hardship you face because of your faith will only add to your good deeds on the Day of Judgement.

Comment: This requires elaboration. What exactly is your fear? What could they do and how credible is the threat? And do you have other options such as Hijrah? In some conditions it is permissible to do so even though not doing it and facing the consequences is better. And in other conditions it is not permissible. This discussion comes under the topic of Taqiya.

Answer (score -1):

Taqiyyah is refraining from expressing an opinion and hiding it or doing something against one's heart for special reasons. Quranic, narrative and rational arguments indicate the permission of taqiya.
The issue of taqiyyah has been one of the common theological and jurisprudential issues in the first centuries AH. Shiites are more famous than other followers of Islamic religions for adhering to the method of taqiya. The reason for this tendency is considered to be various social, cultural, economic pressures on Shiites and the existence of esoteric elements in some Shiite sects.
Verses from the Qur'an, narrations, rational reasons and consensus have been cited for the permission of taqiyyah. Some verses of the Qur'an, including verse 28 of Surah Al-Imran, verse 106 of Surah An-Nahl, and verse 28 of Surah Al-Ghafir, have cited the permission of Taqiyyah. Studying the revelation of these verses will be very useful in understanding more of these verses.
The permission or obligation of taqiyyah in certain circumstances can be deduced from the verses related to urgency and distress; Like verses 173, 185 and 195 of Surah Al-Baqarah, he inferred 145 rewards, 115 bees and 78 Hajj.

Finally, hiding your Islam in special circumstances is not forbidden. But according to the text of the verses and their revelation, I inferred that in normal circumstances it is better to choose another method.
I think that in the face of Islamophobia that is propagated in the media, our decent behavior and respectable personality as a Muslim can be a way to show the truth of Islam and Muslims and to counter the attacks of the opponents of Islam.

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%AA%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%87#%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84%E2%80%8C_%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B2_%D8%AA%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%87